# Best practice to save login API key in storage?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, local-storage, embed

I have an embed.js that requires an api key to send requests to server. To obtain the api key, user must login.

This api key can be used across different websites under different domains. What is the best practice?

Can I save the api key in local storage?

Comment: localStorage is separate for each domain.

Comment: on other sites, probably have to request it every time from master site

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to request a html file using <link> and save the key to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you *can* save the API key in local storage.  However, I'm not sure it's the *best* option.  If it's being sent with every request and the size is less than 4096 bytes then I know cookies are the preffered method of storage and more easily managed through expiry and can be used easier server side.

Since you mention using the key cross domain, I know that there are some widely used options out there for using local storage across different domains such as including a hidden iframe and using it's local storage.  See this [article](https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/cross-domain-localstorage/).

Also, [here](https://github.com/ofirdagan/cross-domain-local-storage) is a javascript library that my fit the bill for cross domain local storage.